# How to fit a nd array which contains sparse matrix into sklearn

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Firstly , I Apply TfidfVectorization on my Text Columns from my dataframe After That i merge them using hsatck

```
train_gene_var_tfidf = 
hstack((train_gene_feature_tfidf,train_variation_feature_tfidf))
test_gene_var_tfidf = 
hstack((test_gene_feature_tfidf,test_variation_feature_tfidf))
cv_gene_var_tfidf = 
hstack((cv_gene_feature_tfidf,cv_variation_feature_tfidf))

# Adding the train_text feature
train_x_tfidf = hstack((train_gene_var_tfidf, train_text))
train_x_tfidf = hstack((train_x_tfidf, train_text_feature_tfidf))
train_y = np.array(list(train_df['Class']))
```

And the result i got a numpy ndarray which contains sparse matrix
I want to fit my function into sklearn .fit() as shown below

```
clf = SGDClassifier(class_weight='balanced',alpha=i,penalty='l2', loss='log', random_state=42)
clf.fit(train_x_tfidf, train_y)
```

the shapes are as follows:

```
print(train_x_tfidf.shape)
print(train_y.shape)
>>>(4,)
>>>(2124,)
print(train_x_tfidf)
>>>[<2124x227 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 2124 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
<2124x1000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 1259 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
<2124x1000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 31088 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
<2124x1000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 1129081 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>]
```

The error i'm getting while tring to fit is

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

How to fit this ndarray into sklearn fit function?

Comment: Don't use hstack to join sparse matrices

Comment: `sparse.hstack` can combine sparse matrices correctly.